# Update values in 2 different .json files using PHP

Tags: php, json

I have 2 .json files, one containing questions and answers with categories and one containing the categories. Here are small parts of the .json files:

*category.json*

```
[{
    "category": "Algemeen"
}]
```

*questions.json*

```
[{
    "category": "Algemeen",
    "question": "123",
    "answer": "123",
    "date": "03-12-18 08:48:16"
}]
```

I have created an overview for the categories, where I can add, edit and delete a category. I have also created an overview for the questions and answers.

When editing the category in the category overview, it will post this into the .json file using the following code:

```
<?php
    //get the index from URL
    $index = $_GET['index'];

    //get json data
    $data = file_get_contents('category.json');
    $data_array = json_decode($data);

    //assign the data to selected index
    $row = $data_array[$index];
?>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['save'])){
        //set the updated values
        $input = array(
            'category' => $_POST['category'],
        );

        //update the selected index
        $data_array[$index] = $input;

        //encode back to json
        $data = json_encode($data_array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        file_put_contents('category.json', $data);

        header('location: category.php');
    }
?>
```

When "Algemeen" is edited into "Algemeen1" using my simple form with save button, this will edit *category.json*  using the code above. This will change into:

```
[{
    "category": "Algemeen1"
}]
```

However, the goal is to have the categories "synced", so that when you edit any category that also exists in *questions.json*, it also edits the value of category in *questions.json*. This has to result into:

```
[{
    "category": "Algemeen1",
    "question": "123",
    "answer": "123",
    "date": "03-12-18 08:48:16"
}]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Loop over your questions JSON, check if the category of an item was the “old” one, if so replace it with the “new” one … and then write the whole thing back in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
<?php
    //get the index from URL
    $index = $_GET['index'];

    //get json data
    $category_data = file_get_contents('category.json');
    $category_data_array = json_decode($data);
    $questions_data = file_get_contents('questions.json');
    $questions_data_array = json_decode($data);

    // get the old category name
    $row = $category_data_array[$index];
    $old_category = $row->category;
?>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['save'])){
        //set the updated values
        $input = array(
            'category' => $_POST['category'],
        );

        //update the selected index
        $category_data_array[$index] = $input;

        // find old category, make new
        foreach($questions_data_array as $question){
            if ($question->category == $old_category) {
                $question->category = $_POST['category'];
                break;
            }
        }


        //encode back to json
        $category_data = json_encode($category_data_array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        file_put_contents('category.json', $category_data);
        $questions_data = json_encode($questions_data_array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        file_put_contents('questions.json', $questions_data);

        header('location: category.php');
    }
?>
```

**Caveat**: I did not test this code. It's like pseudo-code in the shape of actual code.

Comment: $old_category = $category_data_array[$index]['category'];

This does not work, Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: Well shoot, I got pretty close at least. Glad I could help.